# Sequence of functions - integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

If $f_1(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$, $f_2(x)=\int_0^x f_1(t)dt$ and $$f_n(x)=\int_0^x f_{n-1}(t)dt$$ for all $n\ge 2$, prove the following:

1. For $n\in \mathbb N$ $$f_{n+1}(x)=\int \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f(t)dt$$
2. Assume class $C^{n+1}$$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k+\int_0^x f^{n+1}(t)\frac{(x-t)^{n}}{n!}$$

Assume that f is continuous on the interval I containing $0$.

**My Work**

1. For this part, I started by using integration by parts on the function $f_{n+1}$, using $v(x)=\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}$ and $u'(x)=f(t)dt$. I chose these u and v somewhat arbitrarily, but with the idea that I could use the relationship between $f_1$ and $f_2$ to work towards a solution. Unfortunately, while I was able to get some results, the did not seem pertinent to the solution: $$\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}F(t)|^x_0+\frac1{n(n!)}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-1}F(t)dt$$ 
   From here, I do not know how to work towards a final solution
2. To start, I studied how the equation resembled Taylor's Theorem, but honestly, I am pretty intimidated by the problem. I'm not the best at proofs and I really don't know where to even begin to tackle this problem

Comment: How could I alter it while still keeping all of the pertinent information? The question is simply too long for the title bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

\begin{align}
\int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f(t)\:dt&=\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}\left(\int_0^t f(y)\:dy\right)\bigg|_0^x+\int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\left(\int_0^t f(y)\:dy\right)dt
\\
&=\int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f_1(t)\:dt
\\
&=\vdots
\\
&=\int_0^x f_{n}(t)\:dt=f_{n+1}(x)
\end{align}
2) Since
\begin{align}
\int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(t)\:dt&=\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(t)\bigg|_0^x+\int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n)}(t)dt
\\
&=-\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n+\int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n)}(t)\:dt
\\
&=\vdots
\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k+\int_0^x f^{(1)}(t)\:dt
\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k+f(x)-f(0)
\end{align}
We have
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k+\int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}f^{(n+1)}(t)\:dt
$$